# Neyman-Pearson and Stein's Lemma

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

Consider the following problem.

> Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be i.i.d. $\sim P$ taking values from $\mathbb{X}=\{-1,0,1\}$. Consider the hypothesis test $H_1: P=P_1$ vs $H_2: P=P_2$, where
> $$
> P_1(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1/2,& \text{for } x=-1 \\
> 1/4,& \text{for } x=0 \\
> 1/4,& \text{for } x=1\\
> 0& \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> and
> $$
> P_2(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1/4,& \text{for } x=-1 \\
> 1/4,& \text{for } x=0 \\
> 1/2,& \text{for } x=1\\
> 0& \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Find the probability of error in accepting $H_2$ when actually $H_1$ is true while keeping the other probability of error $\le 1/2$ in the best hypothesis test.

First I will apply the Neyman-Pearson lemma to find the required probability of error. Let
$$
A(T)=\left\{x\in\mathbb{X}:\frac{P_1(x)}{P_2(x)}\ge T\right\}
$$
Then, when $T=1$, we have $A(1)=\{-1,0\}$ and $\text{Pr}(\text{Accepting } H_2|H_1 \text{ is true}) = P_1(A(1)^c) = 1/4$ while other probability of error is $P_2(A(1)) = 1/2$.

On the other hand, when $T=2$, $A(2) = \{-1\}$ and $\text{Pr}(\text{Accepting } H_2|H_1 \text{ is true}) = P_1(A(1)^c) = 1/2$ while other probability of error is $P_2(A(1)) = 1/4\le 1/2$.

So in both cases, the condition of other probability of error being $\le 1/2$ is satisfied. So, in a practical situation, what threshold one should take? Is there any result that talks about choosing the best threshold in a practical situation?

Also, in this situation, if we use Stein's lemma, we get $\text{Pr}(\text{Accepting } H_2|H_1 \text{ is true})\approx \exp (-nD(P_2\|P_1)) = \exp (-n/4)$. So, what is preferred, the probability of error that we calculated using Neyman-Pearson lemma or the one calculated using Stein's lemma?

Any help is greatly appreciated.